# Accessing firebase db data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a dashboarding solution for a client who is using Motolog app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.gswierczynski.motolog)
to track miles, work duration and expense tracking. Initially planned on using python(selenium) to scrape data from website, but the developer just has the app and no login via website. After digging in found out the app uses firebase as a DB. Is there a way I can access that data directly from firebase db. Thanks for the help.
Edit: I want the data to be automatically refreshed on my dashboard every 10 minutes or so. Is there any automated way to do that?

Comment: For sure there is. What is the problem with doing that?

Comment: So what is your question? Are you asking about how to get data from this app? They say in the doc that you can export data to XLS, CSV y PDF.

Comment: The data needs to be refreshed every 10 minutes. Is there any automated way to do that.